# why HAWQ Initialization error sync hawq-site.xml failed

Tags: hawq

the apache-hawq-src-2.3.0.0 ,build form source. install is sucessfuly.but

when I init hawq, like this `"bin/hawq init master"`,

> 20180830:13:44:15:084023 hawq_init:office-hadoop02:web-[INFO]:-Check:
>   hawq_master_address_host is set 20180830:13:44:15:084023
>   hawq_init:office-hadoop02:web-[INFO]:-Check: hawq_master_address_port
>   is set 20180830:13:44:15:084023
>   hawq_init:office-hadoop02:web-[INFO]:-Check: hawq_master_directory is
>   set 20180830:13:44:15:084023
>   hawq_init:office-hadoop02:web-[INFO]:-Check: hawq_segment_directory is
>   set 20180830:13:44:15:084023
>   hawq_init:office-hadoop02:web-[INFO]:-Check: hawq_segment_address_port
>   is set 20180830:13:44:15:084023
>   hawq_init:office-hadoop02:web-[INFO]:-Check: hawq_dfs_url is set
>   20180830:13:44:15:084023 hawq_init:office-hadoop02:web-[INFO]:-Check:
>   hawq_master_temp_directory is set 20180830:13:44:15:084023
>   hawq_init:office-hadoop02:web-[INFO]:-Check:
>   hawq_segment_temp_directory is set 20180830:13:44:15:084023
>   hawq_init:office-hadoop02:web-[INFO]:-No standby host configured, skip
>   it 20180830:13:44:15:084023
>   hawq_init:office-hadoop02:web-[INFO]:-Check if hdfs path is available
>   20180830:13:44:15:084023 hawq_init:office-hadoop02:web-[INFO]:-1
>   segment hosts defined 20180830:13:44:15:084023
>   hawq_init:office-hadoop02:web-[INFO]:-Set
>   default_hash_table_bucket_number as: 6 20180830:13:44:17:084023
>   **hawq_init:office-hadoop02:web-[ERROR]:-sync hawq-site.xml failed.
>   20180830:13:44:17:084023 hawq_init:office-hadoop02:web-[ERROR]:-Set
>   default_hash_table_bucket_number failed**

Answer (score 0):

This should because the ssh password-less is not set, please check below settings.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HAWQ/Build+and+Install

> ## Besides you need to set password-less ssh on the systems.
>
> ## Exchange SSH keys between the hosts host1, host2, and host3:
>
> hawq ssh-exkeys -h host1 -h host2 -h host3